# How to use apply in R to subset required columns and for the rest fill with blanks?

Tags: r

This is the Sample data

```
df= data.frame(C = c(0, 2, 4, 7, 8), A = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 8), B = c(1, 3, 8, 3, 2), 
Region = c("US","UK","NZ","OZ","SA")),Status = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes")

#   C A B Region Status
# 1 0 4 1  US     Yes
# 2 2 2 3  UK     No
# 3 4 4 8  NZ     Yes 
# 4 7 7 3  OZ     No
# 5 8 8 2  SA     Yes
```

What i am trying is to select only Region and Status columns and rest keep blanks.

```
selectvar <- c("Region","Status")
lapply(df[which(!names(df) %in% selectvar )],0)
```

I am trying to get this as my final output:

```
# Region Status  C  A  B
#  US     Yes
#  UK     No
#  NZ     Yes 
#  OZ     No
#  SA     Yes
```

Comment: `df[!names(df) %in% c("Region", "Status")] <- ""`

Comment: It was correct solution thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `lapply` at all

```
df[!names(df) %in% c("Region", "Status")] <- ""
```

does the job.

Answer (score 1):

A succinct solution using `replace`:

```
replace(df, 1:3, "")
```

**Output:**

```
  C A B Region Status
1           US    Yes
2           UK     No
3           NZ    Yes
4           OZ     No
5           SA    Yes
```